# Alterar entre tipos de teclados (texto - numeros)

Tags: jquery, apache-cordova

Boa noite. Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo (cordova), que o usuário tem que cadastrar um código inicial com 2 (duas) letras, 14 (quatorze) números e mais 2 letras.

Eu consegui fazer o input mudar para numérico quando chega na segunda letra, mas o teclado acaba não mudando o tipo de dado.
Dei um .blur() e um .focus(), mas o teclado não reaparece.

Alguma sugestão?

```
var espaco = 0;
$('#numeroOS').keyup(function(e) {

if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
  espaco = 0;
  $('#numeroOS').val("");
}

var text = $('#numeroOS').val();

if (text[text.length - 1] != ' ') {
  text.length - espaco;
} else {
  espaco++;
}

if (text.length == 2){
  $('#numeroOS').prop('type', 'tel');
  $('#numeroOS').blur();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#numeroOS').focus();
  },100);     

} else {
  $('#numeroOS').prop('type', 'text');
}
```

Comment: ao invés de só dar o blur, você tentou colocar o foco em outro elemento e depois retornar para o seu input?

Comment: Não tentei isso não, mas uma coisa que vi, que dando foco no elemento, não abre o teclado.